# cplusplus connet mysql show data question

Tags: c++, mysql

````
**``` c++ connect mysql
````

  1.

---

### Heading

````
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
MYSQL *conn;MYSQL_RES *res;MYSQL_ROW row;
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    const char *sever = "127.0.0.1"; //主机
    const char *user = "root"; //用户名
    const char *password = "root"; //用户密码
    const char *database = "demo"; //数据库名称
    conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    if(!mysql_real_connect(conn,sever,user,password,database,3306,NULL,0))
    {
        cout << "connect error" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    mysql_set_character_set(conn,"utf8");
    while(1==1){//where there not work
        cout<<"enter while"<<endl;
        sleep(2);
        cout<<"link ok"<<endl;
        if(mysql_query(conn,"select * from person"))
        {
            cout << "query error" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        //res = mysql_store_result(conn);
        res = mysql_use_result(conn);
        while((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
        {
            cout << row[0] << '\t' << row[1] << '\t' << row[2] << '\t'
                 << row[3] << '\t' << row[4] << endl;
        }
        cout<<"query end"<<endl;
    }
    mysql_free_result(res);
    mysql_close(conn);
    return 0;
}
```
````

1. it can show data from mysql.but why it not cycle.the while doesn't work?
2. i have tried many conform to explain this .but no any one can help my ,some one who can tell my why .

Comment: What is the actual and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: i want it circular printing the data 2 per second.but in only print once. it's strange

Comment: Do you get the output `query error` at the end?